# is it possible to modify the layout of other running applications

Tags: android, android-activity, layout-inflater

Let's say I have an application running in the background that is running displayed on top of other applications, When I run the following function it will change the text, image or color of the currently displayed layout

I have the following code but it only works in the application itself not in other applications

```
int layoutId = getResources().getIdentifier("main", "layout", "package");


LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);

TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_id);

textView.setText("new text");


setContentView(view);
```

If it is possible then what should I learn, or references that I can learn

Comment: Fortunately , what you are seeking is not possible, largely for security reasons, except perhaps on rooted devices.

Comment: Oh That means there is still potential for it to work for rooted devices, where can I learn about it?

Comment: On rooted devices there are multiple possibilities to modify apps. One would be to use an Xposed/LSposed environment and write an module for it. Or there is Frida which allows to attach to apps and hook or replace methods of the app or inject custom code.